# How can I iterate properly through this list

Tags: algorithm, haskell, purely-functional

The following example is a simplification of the problem.
I have a list `[Either Foo Bar]`,and another list `[Biz]`.
The idea is that I iterate each `Biz` element through `[Either Foo Bar]` ,from the beginning of the `[Either Foo Bar]`, until `Biz` is empty. The result will be that there will now be more `Bar`s and less `Foo`s in the `[Either Foo Bar]`

The problem is being able to start at the beginning of `[Either Foo Bar]` when it's time to use the next element in `[Biz]`.

I could post an example of what I am trying to do, if it will help.

Update:
Okay here are the actual types I am using, still trying to leave out what I think may be extraneous information. Please let me know if I have left out something important

`[Either UnFlaggedDay CalendarDay]`
`[(CalFlag,Product, Day)]`

> ```
> data CalFlag = FirstPass
>               | SecondPass
>               | ThirdPass
>                  deriving (Enum,Eq,Show)
> ```

What I'm trying to do is check the `Day` against the `Left` value in `[Either UnFlaggedDay CalendarDay]`. When I get a match, I want make a new list, that is exactly the same excepting the following changes : I will change that `UnFlaggedDay`, plus the next two `UnflaggedDay`s in the list to `CalendarDay`s`. At that point, I want to use the newly built list, that has the same number of elements still, and the`[(CalFlag,Product, Day)]`minus the`(CalFlag,Product, Day)` that was just checked against. Below is some broken code that is in between my different approaches to this problem.

> ```
> flagReserved :: [Either UnFlaggedDay CalendarDay] -> Handler
>                                                      [Either UnFlaggedDay
>                                                              CalendarDay]
> flagReserved ((Left (MkUFD day)):rest) = do
>    reserved <- runDB $ selectList [TestQueue ==. Scheduled_Q,
>                                    TestStatus /<-. [Passed,Failed]] []
>
>   case (L.null reserved) of
>     True -> do
>            processedDays <- ((Left $ MkUFD day) :) <$> flagReserved rest
>            return processedDays
>
>     False -> return $
>            flagReserved' (map prepList ((Left (MkUFD day)):rest))
>                          (flagProductTuple reserved)
>
> flagReserved ((Right (MkCal day)):rest) = do
>     processedDays <- ((Right $ MkCal day):) <$> flagReserved rest
>     return processedDays
> flagReserved _ = return []
>
> flagReserved' :: [Either (UnFlaggedDay) CalendarDay] ->
>                  [(CalFlag,Product,Maybe C.Day)] ->
>                  [Either UnFlaggedDay CalendarDay]
>
> flagReserved' ((Left (MkUFD  day)):restD)
>               ((calFlag,firmware,Just startDate):restF) =
>     case (startDate == day || not (calFlag == FirstPass)) of
>       True   | (calFlag == ThirdPass) ->
>                   flagReserved' ((Right $
>                                   conScheduled day firmware Reserved) : restD) restF
>
>              | otherwise ->
>                  flagReserved (Right $
>                                consScheduled day firmware Reserved) : 
>                                flagReserved' restD
>                                              ((succ calFlag,
>                                                     firmware,
>                                                     Just startDate) :
>                                                     restF)
>       False -> (Left (MkUFD day)) : flagReserved' restD ((calFlag,
>                                                           firmware, 
>                                                           Just startDate) : restF)
>
>
>
>
> flagReserved' ((Right (MkCal (Left (MkAD (dayText,day))))):restD)
>                ((calFlag,firmware,Just startDate):restF) =
>       case (startDate == day || not (calFlag == FirstPass)) of
>                 True | (calFlag == ThirdPass) ->
>                          (Right $ consScheduled day firmware Reserved) :
>                          flagReserved' restD restF
>                      | otherwise ->
>                          (Right $  consScheduled day firmware Reserved) :
>                             flagReserved' restD ((succ calFlag,
>                                                   firmware,
>                                                   Just startDate):restF)
>                 False ->
>                  (Right (MkCal (Left (MkAD (dayText,day))))) :
>                  flagReserved' restD ((calFlag,firmware,Just startDate) :
>                                       restF)
>
>
> flagReserved' ((Right (MkCal (Right unAvailable))):restD)
>                ((calFlag,firmware,startDate):restF) =
>               (Right $
>                MkCal $
>                Right unAvailable) :
>               flagReserved' restD ((calFlag,firmware,startDate) : restF)
>
> flagReserved' unprocessed  [] = unprocessed
> flagReserved' [] _ = []
> ```

Update:

I've made some test code to work out my thoughts. Here's what I have so far

> ```
> let reservedDays = [(FirstPass,IM,C.fromGregorian 2012 01 15),
>                      (FirstPass,WAF,C.fromGregorian 2012 01 14),
>                      (FirstPass,Backup,C.fromGregorian 2012 01 13)
>                    ]
>
> dummyFunc :: [Either UnFlaggedDay CalendarDay] -> (CalFlag,Product,C.Day)
>   dummyFunc dayList (cFlag,product,day) = if day `elem` dayList
>                                          then dummyFunc' dayList (cFlag,product,day)
>                                          else dayList
>
> dummyFunc' dayList (cFlag,product,day) =
>     if (cFlag == ThirdPass)
>     then
> ```

Okay here is where I am stuck. I need to be able to change the next three Left values to Right values. My intent for `dummyFunc'` was to split the list at the first `Left` Value, remove it, add the new `Right` value, join the previously split lists, and repeat two more times. Is there a better way? If not, is there already a function that will split a list in half based on the criteria I mentioned? I can figure out how to do it by hand, but I'm not trying to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Yes, please post the example.

Comment: Yes, an example would definitely help. Without it, could it be `foldl iterateBizFooBar eitherFooBar bizList`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I take it that each element in the `[Biz]` might adjust one or more elements in the `[Either Foo Bar]` away from the left (`Foo`) type and to the right (`Bar`) type.  This is just a fold:

```
eitherList = [Left (), Left (), Right 5, Right 9, Left ()]
bizList = [4,5,6,7,1]

func eitherlst biz = if (Left ()) `elem` eitherlst
                       then Right biz : delete (Left ()) eitherlst
                       else eitherlst

eitherList' = foldl func eitherList bizList
```

The above is untested, but you can see how the updated `eitherList` is passed between each call to `func` as a result of considering the original `eitherList` and all `Biz` elements up to that point.  As you can see, your implementation of `func` is what will make this useful.

Comment: The more I look at this, the more I think a foldl is what I want.

Comment: For those of you looking at Michael's comment - it was a foldr for about 20 seconds after I hit post, but I edited quickly enough that it didn't get a history.

Comment: Oh yeah, I was just saying I think your suggestion moved me in the right direction.